# How can I pass a parameter together with the Model?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, parameters, model, routes

Here's my `View` (Model `ActivityViewModel`):

```
@model GPMS.Models.ActivityViewModel
<div class="tab-pane" id="managepayments" role="tabpanel">
    @{ Html.RenderPartial("_Payments", Model.Payments); }
</div>
```

Which render a Partial (Model `IEnumerable<GPMS.Models.PaymentViewModel>`):

```
@model IEnumerable<GPMS.Models.PaymentViewModel>
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("SavePayments", "Activities", new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST", UpdateTargetId = "DynamicContainer", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, OnBegin = "AjaxBeginFormOnBegin", OnComplete = "AjaxBeginFormOnComplete", OnSuccess = "AjaxBeginFormOnSuccess", OnFailure = "AjaxBeginFormOnFailure" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <!-- My Form -->
}
```

Which send `Ajax` request to my Controller's `Action`:

```
public ActionResult SavePayments(IEnumerable<PaymentViewModel> payments)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid) {
        // code; here I need ActivityViewModel.ID
    }
}
```

The question is: how can I pass to that `SavePayments` also my activity ID stored in `ActivityViewModel.ID`? Can I do with routing?

I don't want to pass the whole `ActivityViewModel` to `SavePayments`, otherwise I need to take care of its required fields for the `ModelState.IsValid` check.

Comment: You define different `@model` types in the parent and the partial, yet you're using the same `Model`. How come?

Comment: Your code would be throwing an exception. You need to show the real code.

Comment: @StephenMuecke: typo! Fixed!

Comment: So why not include the form in the main view?

Comment: @StephenMuecke: because I want to send back/manage only Payments, not the whole Activity. In main view I could have different forms.

Comment: @StephenMuecke: that's weird! When I postback, and I check `ModelState.IsValid`, I need to pass (via hidden) all the required field of `ActivityViewModel`, which is a pain. Else it will fail validation. Considering that the Main View is for show detail of `ActivityViewModel`, not edit it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176121/discussion-between-markzzz-and-stephen-muecke).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to use the overload of `Html.Partial` to pass the `ID` using `additionalViewData`, then retrieve it in the partial view and add it as a route value in the form.

In the main view

```
@{ Html.RenderPartial("_Payments", Model.Payments, new ViewDataDictionary { { "ID", Model.ID} }); }
```

And in the partial

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("SavePayments", "Activities", new { id = ViewData["ID"] }, new AjaxOptions { ....
```

Then add a parameter in the POST method for the ID

```
public ActionResult SavePayments(int id, IEnumerable<PaymentViewModel> payments)
```